The inner product on a vector space whose field is R
if we can make different definitions of the inner product  in a vector space does that mean that the length and angles we get from each can serve different purposes and return different values , meaning we can define d(a,b) in different ways depending on the different inner products that the vector space can have?
where a and b are vectors in the vector space on the real numbers
I assume the problem is that I keep thinking of taking an orthonormal basis and then taking the inner product as a transformation when looking at the the vectors as coordinates vectors in $R^n $ there it seems like getting  different numbers is weird but this is probably because I need to think of a definition that keeps the geometric  logic apparent so I can understand the purposes served (note: would appreciate a definition where the angles can be interrupted differently depending on the inner product , seems like for distances I can think of the distance between two function in different ways like if I am looking at the largest difference between them the area between it seems reasonable that each definition is right for the use we need)

I assume that the answer may be that this is correct , yet it is weird to think of a definition other than the one on$ R^n$ since this one is intuitive but I can see that it can happen when I define different inner products but the one I am randomly defining are leading to confusion nothing else , would appreciate a couple of examples if it is indeed true

Think of it like that: what properties does the inner product have? Then, what other functions do have the same properties?
